# Relationship / Connection Between Machine Learning / Deep Learning and Computer Vision

Tags: computer-vision, machine-learning, deep-learning

What is the actual relationship between Machine learning and Computer vision? Is Computer vision is subset of Machine learning or is it another independent subset of Machine Learning? I am trying to clear this confusion, some internet sources mention Computer vision is subset of Machine learning while some other mention Computer vision is another independent subset of Artificial Intelligence. Please let me know, whether Computer vision is subset of Machine learning or not subset?

Comment: there's non-machine learning computer vision, so that rules out subsets. However, field categorizations are utterly subjective: such questions are off-topic here. What good is an answer that someone "on the internet" gave you? Does it *really* help you categorize things? You already know there's significant overlap.

Comment: I think these questions about « what’s the difference between machine learning and field x » provoque lots of opinion-based responses. For instance, what’s the difference between machine learning and statistics or computational statistics? Or what’s AI?

Comment: @jkh, Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Computer Vision is the application while in many cases Machine Learning is the used framework.

Namely, Computer Vision defines the "what": What is needed to achieve, while Machine Learning is about "how": How can we solve this?

So they have relation but not hierarchical relationship.